# Typo3: How to setup image properties like width, height and alt?

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-6.2.x

I have a snippet of the following typoscript code, that shows image with defined class name. What is lacking is the image's width, height, align etc properties; which have been set in the backend editor.

```
30 = FILES
    30 {
        references {
            table = tt_content
            fieldName = image
        }
        renderObj = IMAGE
        renderObj {
            file.import.data = file:current:publicUrl
            params = class="img-responsive img-centered" 
        }
    }
...
...
}
```

The rendered html is something like: `<img class="img-responsive img-centered" width="600" height="880" border="0" alt="" src="preview.png">`
How do I also show custom width/height/align properties set from backend?

== Added more details ==

Here is my entire block of this segment of code:

```
temp.portfolio = CONTENT
temp.portfolio {
  table = tt_content
  select {
    begin = 1
    orderBy = sorting
    where = (colPos = 2)
    }
    renderObj = COA 
    renderObj {

10 = TEXT  
10 {
  required = 1
  wrap = <a class="portfolio-link" data-toggle="modal" href="#portfolioModal"><div class="portfolio-hover"><div class="portfolio-hover-content"><i class=" | "></i></div></div>
  stdWrap.field = custom_icon
}

15 = FILES
15 {
    references {
        table = tt_content
        fieldName = image
    }
    renderObj = IMAGE

    renderObj {
        file.import.data = file:current:publicUrl
        params = class="img-responsive" 
    }
}

20 = TEXT
20 {
  required = 1
  wrap = </a><div class="portfolio-caption"><h4> | </h4>
  stdWrap.field = header
  #parseFunc =< lib.parseFunc_RTE
}
30 = TEXT
30 {
  required = 1
  wrap = <p class="text-muted"> | </p>
  stdWrap.field = subheader
  #parseFunc =< lib.parseFunc_RTE
}
40 = TEXT
40 {
  wrap = </div>
}

50 = CONTENT
50 {
  table = tt_content
  select {
    uidInList {
      field = header_link
      stdWrap.replacement.10 {
        search = /^.+#/
        replace = 
        useRegExp = 1
      }
    }
    max = 1
    where = (pid = 11)
    pidInList {
      field = header_link
      stdWrap.replacement.10 {
        search = /#.+$/
        replace = 
        useRegExp = 1
      }
    }
  }
  renderObj = COA
  renderObj {
    10 = TEXT  
    10.value {
      required = 1
      wrap = <h2> | </h2>
      field = header
    }
    20 = TEXT  
    20.value {
      required = 1
      wrap = <p class="item-intro text-muted"> | </p>
      field = subheader
    }
    30 = FILES
    30 {
        references {
            table = tt_content
            fieldName = image
        }
        renderObj = IMAGE

        renderObj {
            file {
                import.data = file:current:publicUrl
                width.field = imagewidth
                height.field = imageheight
            }

            params = class="img-responsive img-centered"
            altText.data = file:current:alternative

        }
    }
    40 = TEXT  
    40.value {
      required = 1
      wrap = |
      field = bodytext
      parseFunc =< lib.parseFunc_RTE
    }
    stdWrap.wrap = <span class="float-window" style="display:none"> | </span>
  }
}
stdWrap.wrap = <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 portfolio-item"> | </div>
}
}
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can access the width and height (tt_content fields imagewidth & imageheight) with the `.field =` method and the properties of the image with the `.data = file:current:propertyName` method. I have created a snippet for you below.

```
lib.myContent < styles.content.get
lib.myContent.renderObj = COA
lib.myContent.renderObj {
  10 = FILES
  10 {
    references {
      table = tt_content
      uid.field = uid
      fieldName = image
    }
    renderObj = IMAGE
    renderObj {
      file {
        import.data = file:current:publicUrl
        width.field = imagewidth
        height.field = imageheight
      }
      altText.data = file:current:alternative
      params.cObject = COA
      params.cObject {
        10 = TEXT
        10.value = class="img-responsive img-centered"

        20 = CASE
        20 {
          key.field = imageorient
          default = TEXT
          default.value = center

          2 < .default
          2.value = left
          10 < .2
          18 < .2
          26 < .2

          1 < .default
          1.value = right
          9 < .1
          17 < .1
          25 < .1
        }
        20.stdWrap.noTrimWrap = | align="|"|
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Above code snippet takes all content elements from current page `colPos = 0` and render only the images disregarding content type.

This will output.

```
<img src="/fileadmin/_processed_/csm_file_a51148bd89.jpg" class="img-responsive img-centered" align="center" alt="Your alt text" height="41" width="200">
```

Comment: Thanks Lasse for the reply. It is however not affecting the width and height properties of image I'm afraid. Nonetheless, alt-text field is showing the value from backend. What else can I check? 

`30 = FILES
30 {
 references {
  table = tt_content
  fieldName = image
 }
 renderObj = IMAGE
 renderObj {
  file {
   import.data = file:current:publicUrl
   width.field = imagewidth
   height.field = imageheight
  }
  params = class="img-responsive img-centered"
  altText.data = file:current:alternative
 }
}`

Also how to show the "align" field for left/right/absmiddle options?

Comment: Could you please modify your question and include some of the code before `30 = FILES`. `30 = FILES` only gets the file_reference objects not the tt_content object. Thats why i started my code snippet with `lib.myContent < styles.content.get` to first get the content element where you find the width, height and align properties. Please also note the `uid.field = uid` which declare only to include images for this content element and not all on page.

Comment: Are you sure you have set any width/height on the content element? You could also try to output the value of imagewidth/imageheight below the image by adding `31 = TEXT` & `31.field = imagewidth` right after your `30 = FILES...` configuration.

Comment: Yes, I have set width as 150 & height as 250; the value 150 is also showing after I added your suggested **31 block**. However the image is displaying its real file size only (unaffected by backend value). After this is resolved, I want to also set its "Image Alignment" property to the image.

Comment: Hmmm. I´m currently at work but i will take a look into this as soon as possible. My code snippet is tested with version 7.4. I will try later in version 6.2. Could you post an example HTML output of the image?

Comment: I've added my screenshot to the question.

Comment: I have just tested my snippet in TYPO3 6.2.12 and it works. I have also updated my answer with alignment. Are you sure its not the `15 = FILES` image you see in your output?

Comment: I'm afraid it still is not working. 15 = FILES is for thumbnail image only and upon clicking it, a new div shows up that holds the image I want to scale and align from backend. The alignment property didn't show up either (but interestingly 31.field = imagewidth seem to work and show value 150 from database). Could you check my block of code instead on your system?